# Making a folder with html and node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, directory, directory-structure

I wanted to make a website that takes an input and, using node.js for the backend, makes a folder using `mkdirSync(input.value)`. I have the fs module installed locally and I got it to work when using javascript only, but when I try to make it from a button on a web page it doesn't work. This is my folder and file structure:

- Project folder

  - node_modules
  - src

    - index.html
    - script.js
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json

This is the code in the `index.html` and `script.js` files:

```css
const fs = require("fs")
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
const input = document.querySelector("#in")
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fs.mkdirSync(`./src/${input.value}`)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Document </title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="in">
    <input type="submit" id="btn">

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to do this in the first place? I cannot use PHP since I won't be able to use a server for this project. If you have ANY other ideas please tell me, it might be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing two concepts here that don't belong together. I will try to explain this using your first script:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
```

This line belongs in a nodeJS context and has no idea what browsers, windows or documents are. Even if it knew it would still not work because browsers support ESM syntax, i.e. `import` but not CommonJs' `require`.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
const input = document.querySelector("#in")
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fs.mkdirSync(`./src/${input.value}`)
})
```

Here we are in a browser context. Browsers know nothing about file systems so all they can do is throw an error when they across something like `fs`.

You will need some sort of server/client architecture, I'm afraid, even when it's only a tiny local server.

Comment: thank you, I understand now; now that I checked the console I saw the error, I don't usually use the browser console

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how a backend works:

The backend is NOT a script attached to the HTML document
So, your script.js won't work because it isn't backend code, its frontend code.

You can use [Express.js](https://expressjs.com) to make your backend.

Comment: thank you for your response, but could you please tell me how express.js would help? I haven't used it before and I have no idea about what it can do, I only used js for small front-end stuff until now